# How to get object of model FormView is referring

Tags: django, formview

Having this form

```
class StockTakingForm(forms.Form):
    amount = forms.DecimalField(
                _("Parts now inside storage"),
                max_digits=10,
                decimal_places=4,
                help_text=_("The amount stored for future.")
            )
```

and this view I'm wondering how I can perform an update on referenced object best.

```
class StorageItemStockTakingView(FormView):
    form_class = StockTakingForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('storage_item_list')
    template_name = 'pmgmt/storageitem/stocktaking.html'
```

The section from url.py looks like

```
url(r'^storageitem/(?P<pk>[\w]+)/stocktaking/$', login_required(
   StorageItemStockTakingView.as_view()), name='storage_item_stocktaking'),
```

Now I want to take data submitted with this FormView and perform some actions on a real model. I tried to implement my own save() and form_valid() both in context of form as well as view, but failed to get all information I needed. So pretty much what I want to do:

```
si = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=...)
si.report_stock(amount, request.user)
```

but I'm stuck to find the right position.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If you want to update an actual model instance, you need a ModelForm, and an UpdateView.